# How to open a file on a distant server with XML Reader in php?

Tags: php, xml, ftp, xmlreader

I have got a huge xml file (~ 85 Mo) and I would like to open it with XML Reader (then my script read selected lines). I have downloaded it on my PC and my script works (using Wamp).

Now I would like to do the same online. Server login is *aaa* and password is *bbb* (of course it's an example).

I tried the following statement:

```
$xml = new XMLReader();
if ($xml->open('ftp://aaa:bbb@ftp.website.com/myfile.xml')){
    echo 'OK';
}

while($xml->read()){
    // my script here... 
}
```

It seems I am wrong because my web browser indicates me that the page is too long to load. What is the good way to proceed? Or did I miss something important?

Comment: If I understand what you are saying correctly, you will always have this problem, because XML reader will download the entire XML file to the PHP host before doing anything with it. If you want to handle this any other way, you will probably have to roll your own file wrapper and XML parser for your purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the file in question is an XML it is not wise to partially download it since it will probably break the xml structure making the parser to fail.

You could get a cronjob to retrieve the file occasionally and you would open it from a local location on the server, or retrieve it once and cache it locally so that it would speed subsequent requests.

Comment: Finally, a sensible suggestion... +1

Comment: Yes you're right my goal is to set it as a daily cron job. But what do you mean by a "local location"? I'm on a shared web hosting service.

Comment: @Dacobah Oh well, my English sometimes fail :) I meant that after downloading it via a cronjob, you would open it locally on the server. Btw if it is that big, I would also suggest not parsing it upon user request, maybe have the cronjob parse it upon download and serialize it or save it in a Database.

Comment: @mobius Don't worry me too :) Anyway, I used ftp functions (like ftp_get) to connect and download the file on my server. Now it works! Thanks again it solves my problem!

Answer (score 0):

http://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-script-execution-time-limit-ini_set 
The default execution time is 20 secs or 30, increase it to 1 minute and retry

Comment: The question is not "how do I download the file?", it's (effectively) "how do I avoid having to download the entire file?"

Comment: He stated "my web browser indicates me that the page is too long to load"

Comment: Indeed, and that would be because he also stated `I have got a huge xml file (~ 85 Mo) and I would like to open it with XML Reader` - it is the size of the file that causes the timeout. No one would ever want the user to have to wait for an 85Mb transfer before the page was generated, especially when he also states `then my script read selected lines`

Comment: Maybe (probably yes) - but is that relevant? It would still take the same amount of time to download the file data before it could be hashed. Even though `md5_file()` does not load the whole file into memory at any given time, does not mean it can operate without having access to the entirity of the file's data.

Comment: @DaveRandom Wouldn`t it be better if he had a SOAP or REST api to get the file rather than through FTP? I know that through FTP...download can be slow...

Comment: @DaveRandom he can check if his file exists if so compare md5_file with local file and server (if updates were made) and if changes made delete and download

Comment: If the only way is via FTP, then that's what you have to do. There is no reason why FTP is slower than anything else (notably, HTTP, which is what you would be doing with SOAP) becuase it is just a TCP stream, and the data sent and the transport mechanism will likely be identical. The issue here is "how do you get part of a file". This can be done over HTTP with a `Range:` header and FTP with a `REST` command. But actually, the real issue is "how do you get *the correct* part of a file" - how do you know *which part* of the file you want... And that is where it gets tricky.

Comment: @DaveRandom I haven`t worked with Web Services that much...just know the basics...thanks for the patience Dave :-)

Comment: Regarding the `md5_file()` idea: yes, true - but you still need to transfer the whole file to calculate the hash, so it's no quicker. You could do it over HTTP with an `If-Modified-Since:` header, but only if the data is available over HTTP, the HTTP server supports that header, and you keep track of the date you aquired your local copy. If the XML file is dynamically generated upon request, this is unlikely to work at all. Over FTP, howver, this is unlikely to be the case - and `filemtime()` (usually) works over FTP

Answer (score 0):

I would use curl to connect to the FTP server and download the file.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: The question is not "how do I download the file?", it's (effectively) "how do I avoid having to download the entire file?"

Answer (score 0):

Your probably best to download the file to the server first using PHP's [FTP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) and then open the file locally. I wouldn't rely on using FTP within the XML library, you'll get more flexibility this way.

Comment: The question is not "how do I download the file?", it's (effectively) "how do I avoid having to download the entire file?"